# Hue Bridge has a light with ID 0 but cannot to affect it via the API

Tags: node.js, philips-hue

I have a hue bridge 2.0. Out of the box it has 2 lights registered with ids:

- 0
- 1

When I attempt to send an API call to light ID 0, I get the following error:

> The light id '0' is not valid for this Hue Bridge.

I am using the [node-hue-api](https://github.com/peter-murray/node-hue-api) to communicate with the bridge.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a process for getting around it?

The best I have come up with is that I could deregister light 0 and re-register it and, I assume, it should get a new ID.

Comment: That is probably your best bet